# Universal Windows Platform/UAP: what is AOT?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, uwp, nuget, nuget-package

I recently created a blank UWP application in Visual Studio 2015, and then tried to add a nuget package to that application. The package installation failed and resulted in the following messasges in the output window...

```
System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-arm-aot.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64-aot.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x86-aot.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
```

Looking around, I have found references to the "runtimes" within the "project.json"; (mine looks like this)...

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.1.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

My question is this: what is the difference between each "runtime" and the equivalent runtime with "-aot" appended?

I have seen some posts that indicate I can delete these runtimes if I want to use a nuget package that does not support them, but I would prefer to only delete them knowing what they are.

Note: I do not know if this makes any difference, but the UWP application that I am building is expected to only ever be side-loaded (it is a line of business application). It may however eventually need to be distributed via the Windows *Business* Store in order to ease updates etc.

Thanks.

Comment: It means "Ahead of Time".  The opposite of "Just in Time".  Describes the way the intermediate code in your assemblies get compiled to machine code.  The AOT compiler in UWP is better known as .NET Native.  And yes, quite incompatible with Reflection.Emit since that always requires the just-in-time compiler.  You can't use it in a UWP app.

Comment: @Martin Robins, Any update for this issue? Could you get useful information from below answer?

Comment: Did you solve this by modifying the project.json file?

Answer (score 5):

Runtime is a general term that refers to any library, framework, or platform that your code runs on. The win10-arm and win10-arm-aot runtimes are different platforms. Here is a Wikipedia: [Runtime system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_system).
Besides, as per Wikipedia [Ahead-of-time (AOT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation):

> Ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation is the act of compiling a high-level
>   programming language such as C or C++, or an intermediate language
>   such as Java bytecode or .NET Common Intermediate Language (CIL) code,
>   into a native (system-dependent) machine code with the intention of
>   executing the resulting binary file natively.
>       Some programming languages with a managed code runtime that can be compiled to an intermediate language, take advantage of just-in-time
>   (JIT)

So I agree with Hans Passant, the AOT compiler is incompatible with System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration package. So you can delete these aot runtimes if you want to use this package.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my case. I had several projects in my solution and all of them were using

> Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform V 5.2.3

except for one project. It was using

> Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform V 5.0.0

When I update the 5.0.0 to 5.2.3 all the errors went away.

**NOTE: You do not need to remove aot tags from the JSON files.**