# Package incompatible in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

The UWP app I'm working on suddenly throws these errors. However, even with these errors project builds successfully. I just need to know what happens here.

[image]

Comment: Reflection.Emit is not supported in UWP applications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Universal Windows Platform/UAP: what is AOT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42008460/universal-windows-platform-uap-what-is-aot)

Comment: Hi, Please feel free to ask for additional information. At the moment VS does not display anything additional regarding this errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my case. I had several projects in my solution and all of them were using

> Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform V 5.2.3

except for one project. It was using

> Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform V 5.0.0

When I update the 5.0.0 to 5.2.3 all the errors went away.